# Can I cancel a mission

Tags: fallout-tactics

I have entered the level *Peoria* thinking it's a regular mission, until I met two laser turrets and spent almost all my regular ammo to destroy them. Usually I gather plenty of ammo from dead enemies, but this level is different, the enemies are mostly animals and have no loot at all.

Now I don't see any way to complete the mission. When I return to the starting point, I cannot leave the map since there is no green exit area.

Comment: In regards to mission itself you can simply run past the turrets (this is intentional that they have so much health and armour)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think Fallout Tactics has a feature that lets you restart from the beginning of a mission. You're probably going to have to load a previous save, however much progress that may lose you.

As a tip for next time: Fallout Tactics has a lot of quirks. Namely, those turrets in Peoria can be easily defeated when deactivated by feeding them a ton of drugs/chems. They overdose and die after a moderate amount, even though they're not biological.

If you don't have the drugs, melee weapons that can penetrate their armor are your best bet. Despite how dangerous they are at range, they actually have awful accuracy at melee range and are reasonably safe to stab to death. I think you can use the diamond spears you can buy from the Quartermaster.

Comment: +1 for force-feeding turrets drugs until the overdose shuts them down.

Comment: This drugs trick is actually an exploit, isn't it?

Comment: I would say so. How do you even feed a closed turret gum, inhalers, and pills? I think feeding drugs to non-biological targets is just a scenario the game developers never coded for.

Comment: So I've beaten that mission using shotguns at melee range. Even the normal shells do about 10 points of damage on average. With 4 shooters a turret goes down in about 10 turns.